# YouTube API - List all channels that I manage

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api, google-plus, youtube-channels

I have a YouTube channel for my personal account, and one for my business account. I have associated a Google+ page to both channels.  In the business account, I have clicked "Managers" (in the drop down in the top right), and added my personal gmail account as a Manager.  This has all worked fine.

Now, though, I am trying to use the YouTube API to list all of the channels that my personal account has rights to manage.  I'm trying to use the Google Developer's page here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it but it is only returning the one channel that is directly associated with my personal account. I'd expect it to return both the personal channel and the business channel.

Is there a way, an api call, or a setting that will allow me to make a single api call for an oauth user and see all of the YouTube channels / Google+ Pages that the user has permissions to manage?

Comment: The YouTube API does not have the same exposure to G+ manager roles that the YouTube.com site itself does, so as far as the API is concerned your oAuth token is only valid for your personal site. There is a provision in the API to allow one oAuth user to manage multiple accounts, but you have to be a YouTube content partner and the account associations must be set up under those policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can manage different accounts (even if they have linked to eachother) with the same API key. Sub-channels can be managed with the same API key with main channel. Which version of API are you using?

Comment: I was just trying to use the developers page (which is v3, I think). Theoretically, I should be able to manage multiple pages. [https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2380625?hl=en](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2380625?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

I you are using the WebView for authentication, the user has to choose the YouTube account to be used. The channel will then be returned. If you are using Android OAuth, the only way to specify a channel is for the user to select the "default channel" in the advanced YouTube account settings.

http://youtube-eng.blogspot.de/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api_24.html